# Running GeneRegulatoryNetwork package Pando results in MatrixGenerics error: "MatrixGenerics:::.load_next_suggested_package_to_search(x)"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have put my query on several platforms but haven't received any response yet. So I am trying my luck here.
I ran the Joint RNA and ATAC multiomic tutorial till the Peak Calling and added MACS2 peak set to the Seurat Object (d149 in this case) and started running Pando from thereon. But later I get error in MatrixGenerics:::. I am not sure what I did wrong. Please help. I have ran this on 3 different systems and still getting the same error! Is there a sequence/order to which packages are installed in R?

```
library(Pando)

data(motifs)

d149.pando <-Seurat::FindVariableFeatures(d149, assay='RNA')


Calculating gene variances
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|

Calculating feature variances of standardized and clipped values
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|

> d149.pando <- initiate_grn(d149.pando)

> d149.pando <- find_motifs(
    d149.pando,
    pfm = motifs,
    genome = BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38
)
Adding TF info
Building motif matrix
Finding motif positions
Creating Motif object

> d149.pando <- infer_grn(d149.pando)
Selecting candidate regulatory regions near genes
Error in MatrixGenerics:::.load_next_suggested_package_to_search(x) : 
  Failed to find a rowMaxs() method for lgCMatrix objects.

    
    sessionInfo()
    R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
    Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
    
    Matrix products: default
    BLAS/LAPACK: /ncbs_gs/nlsas_data/usershares/praghu/yojetsharma/.conda/envs/Signac/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so
    
    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=C                 LC_NUMERIC=C              
     [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
     [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
     [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
     [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
    [8] base     
    
    other attached packages:
     [1] DelayedMatrixStats_1.19.0         DelayedArray_0.23.2              
     [3] Matrix_1.5-1                      MatrixGenerics_1.9.1             
     [5] matrixStats_0.62.0                Pando_0.5.1                      
     [7] BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38_1.4.4 BSgenome_1.65.2                  
     [9] rtracklayer_1.57.0                Biostrings_2.65.6                
    [11] XVector_0.37.1                    EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86_2.99.0        
    [13] ensembldb_2.21.5                  AnnotationFilter_1.21.0          
    [15] GenomicFeatures_1.49.7            AnnotationDbi_1.59.1             
    [17] Biobase_2.57.1                    GenomicRanges_1.49.1             
    [19] GenomeInfoDb_1.33.7               IRanges_2.31.2                   
    [21] S4Vectors_0.35.4                  BiocGenerics_0.43.4              
    [23] sp_1.5-0                          SeuratObject_4.1.2               
    [25] Seurat_4.2.0                      Signac_1.8.0                     
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
      [1] rappdirs_0.3.3              scattermore_0.8            
      [3] R.methodsS3_1.8.2           tidyr_1.2.1                
      [5] ggplot2_3.3.6               bit64_4.0.5                
      [7] knitr_1.40                  R.utils_2.12.0             
      [9] irlba_2.3.5                 data.table_1.14.2          
     [11] rpart_4.1.16                KEGGREST_1.37.3            
     [13] TFBSTools_1.35.0            RCurl_1.98-1.8             
     [15] generics_0.1.3              cowplot_1.1.1              
     [17] RSQLite_2.2.17              RANN_2.6.1                 
     [19] future_1.28.0               ggpointdensity_0.1.0       
     [21] bit_4.0.4                   tzdb_0.3.0                 
     [23] spatstat.data_2.2-0         xml2_1.3.3                 
     [25] httpuv_1.6.6                SummarizedExperiment_1.27.3
     [27] assertthat_0.2.1            DirichletMultinomial_1.39.0
     [29] viridis_0.6.2               xfun_0.33                  
     [31] hms_1.1.2                   promises_1.2.0.1           
     [33] fansi_1.0.3                 restfulr_0.0.15            
     [35] progress_1.2.2              caTools_1.18.2             
     [37] dbplyr_2.2.1                igraph_1.3.5               
     [39] DBI_1.1.3                   htmlwidgets_1.5.4          
     [41] spatstat.geom_2.4-0         purrr_0.3.4                
     [43] ellipsis_0.3.2              dplyr_1.0.10               
     [45] backports_1.4.1             annotate_1.75.0            
     [47] biomaRt_2.53.2              deldir_1.0-6               
     [49] sparseMatrixStats_1.9.0     vctrs_0.4.1                
     [51] ROCR_1.0-11                 abind_1.4-5                
     [53] cachem_1.0.6                withr_2.5.0                
     [55] grr_0.9.5                   ggforce_0.3.4              
     [57] progressr_0.11.0            checkmate_2.1.0            
     [59] sctransform_0.3.5           GenomicAlignments_1.33.1   
     [61] prettyunits_1.1.1           goftest_1.2-3              
     [63] cluster_2.1.4               lazyeval_0.2.2             
     [65] seqLogo_1.63.0              crayon_1.5.1               
     [67] hdf5r_1.3.6                 pkgconfig_2.0.3            
     [69] tweenr_2.0.2                nlme_3.1-159               
     [71] ProtGenerics_1.29.0         nnet_7.3-17                
     [73] pals_1.7                    rlang_1.0.5                
     [75] globals_0.16.1              lifecycle_1.0.2            
     [77] miniUI_0.1.1.1              filelock_1.0.2             
     [79] BiocFileCache_2.5.0         dichromat_2.0-0.1          
     [81] polyclip_1.10-0             lmtest_0.9-40              
     [83] Matrix.utils_0.9.8          zoo_1.8-11                 
     [85] base64enc_0.1-3             ggridges_0.5.3             
     [87] png_0.1-7                   viridisLite_0.4.1          
     [89] rjson_0.2.21                bitops_1.0-7               
     [91] R.oo_1.25.0                 KernSmooth_2.23-20         
     [93] blob_1.2.3                  stringr_1.4.1              
     [95] parallelly_1.32.1           spatstat.random_2.2-0      
     [97] readr_2.1.2                 jpeg_0.1-9                 
     [99] CNEr_1.33.0                 scales_1.2.1               
    [101] memoise_2.0.1               magrittr_2.0.3             
    [103] plyr_1.8.7                  ica_1.0-3                  
    [105] zlibbioc_1.43.0             compiler_4.2.0             
    [107] BiocIO_1.7.1                RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
    [109] fitdistrplus_1.1-8          Rsamtools_2.13.4           
    [111] cli_3.4.0                   listenv_0.8.0              
    [113] patchwork_1.1.2             pbapply_1.5-0              
    [115] htmlTable_2.4.1             Formula_1.2-4              
    [117] MASS_7.3-58.1               mgcv_1.8-40                
    [119] tidyselect_1.1.2            stringi_1.7.8              
    [121] yaml_2.3.5                  latticeExtra_0.6-30        
    [123] ggrepel_0.9.1               grid_4.2.0                 
    [125] VariantAnnotation_1.43.3    fastmatch_1.1-3            
    [127] tools_4.2.0                 future.apply_1.9.1         
    [129] parallel_4.2.0              rstudioapi_0.14            
    [131] TFMPvalue_0.0.8             foreign_0.8-82             
    [133] gridExtra_2.3               farver_2.1.1               
    [135] Rtsne_0.16                  ggraph_2.0.6               
    [137] BiocManager_1.30.18         digest_0.6.29              
    [139] rgeos_0.5-10                pracma_2.4.2               
    [141] shiny_1.7.2                 motifmatchr_1.19.0         
    [143] Rcpp_1.0.9                  later_1.3.0                
    [145] RcppAnnoy_0.0.19            httr_1.4.4                 
    [147] biovizBase_1.45.0           colorspace_2.0-3           
    [149] XML_3.99-0.10               tensor_1.5                 
    [151] reticulate_1.26             splines_4.2.0              
    [153] uwot_0.1.14                 RcppRoll_0.3.0             
    [155] spatstat.utils_2.3-1        graphlayouts_0.8.1         
    [157] mapproj_1.2.8               plotly_4.10.0              
    [159] xtable_1.8-4                jsonlite_1.8.0             
    [161] poweRlaw_0.70.6             tidygraph_1.2.2            
    [163] R6_2.5.1                    Hmisc_4.7-1                
    [165] pillar_1.8.1                htmltools_0.5.3            
    [167] mime_0.12                   glue_1.6.2                 
    [169] fastmap_1.1.0               BiocParallel_1.31.12       
    [171] codetools_0.2-18            maps_3.4.0                 
    [173] utf8_1.2.2                  lattice_0.20-45            
    [175] spatstat.sparse_2.1-1       tibble_3.1.8               
    [177] curl_4.3.2                  leiden_0.4.3               
    [179] gtools_3.9.3                GO.db_3.15.0               
    [181] interp_1.1-3                survival_3.4-0             
    [183] munsell_0.5.0               GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8     
    [185] reshape2_1.4.4              gtable_0.3.1               
    [187] spatstat.core_2.4-4
```

Comment: This question could use some more information. What exactly is the error you keep getting?

Comment: Hi, the error that I keep getting is:
"Error in MatrixGenerics:::.load_next_suggested_package_to_search(x) : 
  Failed to find a rowMaxs() method for lgCMatrix objects."